# How to declare basic deadline timer in class definition

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Sorry for asking such a basic question but so far all the examples that I have seen on the net for using the basic deadline timer simply initializes the timer as follows

```
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(ioservice);
```

How do I declare this timer as a part of a class. If I try something like

```
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
```

Then how do I assign the ioservice object to it?

I dont see an option like **timer.ioservice = ioservice**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a reference to the IO service to the constructor of the surrounding class, and then construct the timer in the constructors initializing list:

```
class ClassWithTimer
{
public:
    ClassWithTimer(boost::asio::io_service &io_service)
        : timer(io_service)  // Constructs the timer
        { }

private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any other options available? like initializing within a member function, etc

Comment: @MananShah: If you are in a member function, the object has already be constructed (and by extension its sub-objects have also already been constructed), so the timer must have already been initialized.